# Is possible ton insert a VueJs Component with jquery?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have a big application and i used to use jquery to change view dynamically:

```
$(function(){
    $(".changeview").bind("click",function(){     
        $.post(linkAction,phpData,function(data){
                $('#loaded').append(data);                                    
        },"json");
    });

});
```

Now that I have discovered VueJs I was wondering if I could occasionally load completely autonomous vuejs components. In data i return a vue Component (in json) like this:

```
<div id="app">        
        <ul>
            <li v-for="p in persons">
                {{p.nom}}, {{p.prenom}}, {{p.age}}
            </li>
        </ul>
     
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                persons:[{
                    "prenom": "Emalee",
                    "nom": "Ridges",
                    "age": 55
                    },{
                    "prenom": "Lil",
                    "nom": "Tuvey",
                    "age": 38
                    }]
            },
        
        })
    </script>
```

But the vue component is not shown as a component but is show as text

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined**

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you right ! The VueJs module was not loaded.
Now its good and the error is :

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app
```

it's like Vue () is trying to run when my dom is not yet finished updating and my id #app tag doesn't exist yet does it?

Answer (score 0):

Double check that you’re including the vue.js script reference

Comment: Yes i include <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script> into the bottom of main page.